# How do I add a new table and/or field to an "external" Azure SQL Database using a Lightswitch project?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, visual-studio-lightswitch

I created a new Lightswitch (VB 2013) application using an existing external Azure SQL that I had created with a previous Lightswitch (VB 2012) application project.  Everything worked fine. I was able to create new screens and publish the application and use the application with the existing data.
However, now I would like to add new fields, tables and relationships. How can I make those additions in what is now and "external" data source in way that the Lightswitch project will behave as if it were the original application project?
While Lightswitch can be used to integrate separate data sources I would like to keep it as simple as possible.
Do I create the table or add a field in in the Azure portal? When I try to a add a field (or property) in Lightswitch it automatically shows as a "computed" property. When I try make a new table and add a relationship it "asks for more information".
Or is this just the way it works, and is necessarily going to work?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to use LightSwitch to make changes/additions to a database is by using the LightSwitch project that was originally used to create the database. If you still have a copy of the original VS 2012 project, you could open it in VS 2013, make whatever changes you like, and redeploy.

If you don't have a copy of the original project, then you'll have to use a tool outside of LightSwitch to make changes to the database (as you suspected). The LightSwitch project can only make changes in the schema of the database that's defined in that project -- not in attached external data sources like you have in the new project.

Comment: I cannot get the original project to publish to Azure.  I have been able to add a new field to the Azure SQL table but I am unable to get the new field to show up in the project.  VS/Azure prompts for credentials but no matter what format I use, they are not excepted.